# Hide parent element when img src is empty wih jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, element, parent

Generated html:

```
<div class="fp-thumbnail"> <img src="" /></div>
```

Seems to me this should hide the div:

```
$('div').has('img[src=""]').addClass('hide');
```

Css (not sure if this is needed):

```
.hide{display:none !important;}
```

Update: It does work in a js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dHMk4/ but not on the site.

To be more specific: I want to hide the whole div not just the image.

2nd update: None of the solutions given worked any better in practice than what I already had, so I did it a different way. For those who at least tried, thanks for the help.

Comment: [It seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/QxBu8/).

Comment: @dystroy It does seem to in a js fiddle but not on the site.

Comment: @matt then you need to provide more information and perhaps perform basic debugging

Comment: Indeed your code is working. Could you check on the site if there is a Javascript error that could stop the process of the rest of the code. Check also the version of jQuery on your web site.

Comment: Why the upvote? The question clearly states there is not enough information to answer (unless it was meant as a self-answer)

Comment: Note that "doesn't work" is never a good description. I, for one, expected a differnt failure mode than @Musa pointed it out to be

Comment: Turns out "doesn't work" means "hides too much", not "hides too little" in this case

Comment: @user1073122 No js errors in error console. jquery is v1.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$("img[src='']").parent(".fp-thumbnail").addClass("hide");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PQcZq/

Comment: Note that the asker's original code works as well - a fiddle proves nothing

Comment: @JanDvorak the original fiddle will select all divs that are ancestors on the image not just its parent.

Comment: @Musa this explanation deserves to be a part of an answer, or an answer by itself

Answer (score 1):

you can try this approach

```
var $img = $('img');       // Cache the images

$img.each(function(){      // Loop over multiple image tags
   var $this = $(this);    
  if( $this.attr('src') === ''){      // If src is empty
      $this.closest('div.fp-thumbnail').hide();  // Hide the corresponding parent
  }
});
```

If you want to do this for only a specific image you can remove the `.each loop` and specify the specific selector for the image.

Comment: Note that the asker's original code works as well